# Как искусственно отправить несколько запросов на сервер?

Tags: php, post, get

Ребят, всех приветствую.

Опишу в кратце суть:
Есть приложение, в котором бывают "секунды открытия"(например в первую секунду каждого часа очень большая активность и отправляется много запросов от пользователей). И логика программы работает не совсем верно в эти секунды, так как последующие записи зависимы от предыдущих.

Я знаю как исправить это, но единственное, для чистоты эксперимента и чтобы полностью разобраться в проблеме, мне нужно как-то искусственно воссоздать эту ситуацию и продебажить её.
Есть ли какие-то инструменты или методы? В postman'е не нашел такого.

Запрос отправляется get с двумя параметрами.

Заранее премного благодарен за наводку.

Comment: curl вам в помощь. Я лично эмулировал такие ситуации, путём вставки длинной паузы в код, запуска скрипта, убирал паузу и запускал параллельно тот же самый скрипт. На заметку, если у вас запрос get модифицирует данные, то это должен быть post запрос

Comment: @ArchDemon в том то и дело, если сделать паузу между итерациями, то логика верна. Однако когда идут несколько параллельных запросов, то структура строится неверно.

Comment: Паузу нужно ставить в правильном месте (где, по вашему, нарушается логика). Например, после выборки предыдущей записи

Answer (score 2):

Нашел способ. [Apache JMeter](http://jmeter.apache.org/download_jmeter.cgi) Очень широкий функционал, и подходит под большинство задач на тему тестирования своих веб приложения. Начиная с теста на нагрузку заканчивая чем душе угодно. Под мою задачу подошел, ошибку воспроизвел.

Так же на youtube нашел русскоязычный туториал по программе, хотя там и документация достаточно подробная, но чтобы втянуться можно посмотреть. [Ссылка на тутор](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=vxCZl27qPd8)